# Как добавить данные в массив

Tags: ruby

Получаю список файлов из директории и хочу вставить в массив

```
require 'find'
dir = '/home/radzhab/rifc/public/uploads/ckeditor/attachments'
arr = {}
Find.find(dir) { |e| arr.fetch(e) if !File.directory?(e) puts e }
```

По ходу что то делаю не так

Comment: так вам нужен массив или все таки хэш ( как в вашем коде ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам все таки нужен массив

```
    require 'find'
    dir = './'
    arr = []
    Find.find(dir) { |e| arr.push(e) unless File.directory?(e) }
    puts arr # ["./.bash_logout", "./.bashrc", "./.profile", "./_test_runner.rb"]
```

Если нужен хэш, -  как у вас в примере используйте `arr << :key "bar"` или `arr [:newKey] = "newValue"` для примера

Answer (score 1):

### Переусложняете.

...если, конечно, вам нужен именно **массив**, а не хэш/хэшмап (`{}`, который указан в коде). Потому что какие осмысленные *разные* ключи вам нужны для хэшмапа, вы не указали.

`Find.find(dir)`, если не передать ему блок, возвращает `Enumerator`, который содержит в себе [модуль `Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html), швейцарский нож для разного рода перечислителей элементов (коими являются и коллекции, к примеру). И там есть [метод `reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject), который возвращает массив из всех элементов, кроме тех, что подошли под указанное условие.

```
arr = Find.find(dir).reject { |path| File.directory?(path) }
```

При наличии `Enumerable` в подобных мелких алгоритмах нет никакой необходимости. Но раз уж взялись... `Hash#fetch` это вообще операция **чтения**. Не знаю, чего вы хотели добиться, используя её :)